# What's the difference between running flow and flow check?

Tags: flowtype

I'm not totally clear on what `flow check` does vs just `flow`. Running `flow` seems to start a server up, and checks all the code. Subsequent executions of `flow` are faster due to the running server. `flow check` also seems to do a full code check but without the server.

Is there more to it than that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yep, you seem to get it!

---

`flow server` does a full check of your code from scratch. Once it is done, it watches for changes, and incrementally checks your code as it changes.

`flow start` basically runs `flow server` in the background.

`flow check` is basically the same thing as `flow server`, except as soon as it's done with the initial full check, it prints the errors and exits.

`flow status` talks to the running `flow server` and asks for the current errors. If no server is running, it calls `flow start` to start a new server.

`flow` (with no explicit command) is an alias for `flow status`

Answer (score 3):

Another distinction is `flow check` will ignore the currently running server.

I learned this after finding that running `flow` and `flow check` randomly yielded two different results. Truth is, I had run `flow`, added `flow-typed` stuff, and then run `flow check`.